# Is there a .net profiler that can be controlled programatically

Tags: .net, profiling

I am looking for a .net profiler to incorporate to my nightly build process. I've already seen the most of profilers listed on this question [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers) but they don't seem to meet my requirements.

Does anyone know a profiler in which a can programatically:

1. Instrument my application, if necessary
2. Reset counters and take multiple snapshots during execution

Basically, i want something like what the EQATEC Profiler used to provide. Reset counters and take snapshots functionalities, but programatically.